# How do I execute a command on a specific screen?

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I am currently setting up a server and there are different programs I want to run in the background, while still being able to look at the console of each program on demand.

So I'm trying to automatically create a screen for each program and start the program inside of the created screen, but the commands inside the screen dont seem to be running.

I am creating a screen with `screen -dmS screen1` and trying to run a command with `screen -S screen1 -X cmd`, but the screen doesnt do anything.
For example, if I run `screen -S screen1 -X touch /home/user/test`, the file isnt created.

The autostart problem is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send an *enter* for that to work. To do so, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then type <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For example, your command would look like this:

```
screen -S screen1 -X stuff 'touch /home/user/test^M'
```

Keep in mind that will just 'stuff' text into your first window, that will fail if there's already some 'text' in the console.

Take a look at [GNU screen FAQ: How to send a command to a window in a running screen session from the commandline](http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq#how_to_send_a_command_to_a_window_in_a_running_screen_session_from_the_commandline) for additional examples.

One way to do so at screen startup is using `.screenrc` with something like:

```
# Start some screens by default
screen -t touch -L /bin/sh -c "touch ~/test3;bash"
screen -t mc -L /bin/sh -c "mc;bash"
```